# What is the meaning of the bubbles / spikes in the shap values ​plot?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, machine-learning-model, plotting

Here are an example of shap values plot from [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/65307/how-to-interpret-shapley-value-plot-for-a-model).
How to interpret the 'bubble' or 'spikes' on this shap values plot I highlighted in yellow color?

[image: Example of Shap Values Plot]

Answer (score 1):

That's to help indicate the volume of points in that region, which would be lost due to overlap if all plotted along the horizontal line.  This kind of plot is referred to as a "bee-swarm", and is somewhat similar to violin plots, strip plots, or scatter plots with jitter.